# How to combine 'longtable' + 'tabularX' (2-page table with long headings)

Tags: latex, tex, longtable

'tabularx' solves the problem of long headers (does not fit otherwise in width). 'longtable' solves the problem of table length (does not fit in length). But how to solve both problems?

```latex
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline 
    Район & Количество заявок & Количество заявок на тыс. человек & Место по    количеству заявок & Место по количеству заявок на тыс. человек \\ 
    \hline 
    Невский & 1185 & 2.28 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    \hline 
    Фрунзен-ский & 655 & 1.63 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    \hline 
    Примор-ский & 559 & 0.99 & 3 & 8 \\ 
    \hline 
    Калинин-ский & 458 & 0.85 & 5 & 9 \\ 
    \hline 
    Красносель-ский & 284 & 0.74 & 6 & 11 \\ 
    \hline 
    Василеос-тровский & 213 & 1.02 & 9 & 7 \\ 
    \hline 
    Кировский & 275 & 0.82 & 7 & 10 \\ 
    \hline 
    Централь-ный & 231 & 1.04 & 8 & 6 \\ 
    \hline 
    Пушкин-ский & 472 & 2.27 & 4 & 2 \\ 
    \hline 
    Красногвар-дейский & 132 & 0.37 & 12 & 16 \\ 
    \hline 
    Московский & 153 & 0.44 & 11 & 14 \\ 
    \hline 
    Выборгский & 182 & 0.36 & 10 & 17 \\ 
    \hline 
    Петрог-радский & 91 & 0.67 & 14 & 12 \\ 
    \hline 
    Адмирал-тейский & 68 & 0.42 & 15 & 15 \\ 
    \hline 
    Петрод-ворцовый & 65 & 0.46 & 16 & 13 \\ 
    \hline 
    Курортный & 100 & 1.30 & 13 & 5 \\ 
    \hline 
    Кронштад-ский & 60 & 1.36 & 17 & 4 \\ 
    \hline 
    Колпинский & 55 & 0.29 & 18 & 18 \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabularx}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \caption{Заголовок большой таблицы.}\\
    \hline
    \textbf{Район} & \textbf{кол-во заявок} & \textbf{кол-во заявок на тыс. чел.} & \textbf{место по кол-ву заявок} \textbf{место по кол-ву заявок на тыс. чел.} \\ \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    RND1 & RND2 & RND3 & RND4 \\ \hline
    \endhead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{продолжение следует\ldots} \
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot

    \hline 
    Невский & 911 & 1.75 & 1 & 6 \\ 
    \hline 
    Фрунзен-ский & 722 & 1.80 & 3 & 5 \\ 
    \hline 
    Примор-ский & 503 & 0.89 & 7 & 10 \\ 
    \hline 
    Калинин-ский & 251 & 0.47 & 11 & 13-14 \\ 
    \hline 
    Красносель-ский & 499 & 1.30 & 8 & 8 \\ 
    \hline 
    Василеос-тровский & 614 & 2.94 & 4 & 2 \\ 
    \hline 
    Кировский & 396 & 1.18 & 10 & 9 \\ 
    \hline 
    Централь-ный & 498 & 2.24 & 9 & 4 \\ 
    \hline 
    Пушкинс-кий & 155 & 0.74 & 12 & 11 \\ 
    \hline 
    Красногвар-дейский & 598 & 1.67 & 5 & 7 \\ 
    \hline 
    Московский & 905 & 2.58 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    \hline 
    Выборгский & 123 & 0.24 & 13 & 16 \\ 
    \hline 
    Петрог-радский & 571 & 4.24 & 6 & 1 \\ 
    \hline 
    Адмирал-тейский & 89 & 0.54 & 14 & 12 \\ 
    \hline 
    Петрод-ворцовый & 55 & 0.39 & 15 & 15 \\ 
    \hline 
    Курортный & 36 & 0.47 & 17 & 13-14 \\ 
    \hline 
    Кронштад-ский & 10 & 0.23 & 18 & 17-18 \\ 
    \hline 
    Колпинский & 44 & 0.23 & 16 & 17-18 \\ 
    \hline 

\end{longtable}
```

Please show how to make a table that will be moved to the next page, but fit in width

Comment: Try the xltabular package and environment. It is supposed to be combination of tabularx and lontable.

Comment: see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/491188/combining-tabularx-and-longtable

Comment: Hi! Can you ad to the body of question your whole header? Thank you:)